# Pass a variable dynamically into Ansible template while iterating a list in playbook

Tags: jinja2, ansible

Ansible gurus I need your help. I have a template with a variable I need to set dynamically while iterating through a list in the playbook. It's not clear how to "inject" a variable to the template to use while iterating.

Objective is to create many config files in a directory, one for each var in a list. For example if the list is `A, B, C` I would want files A.conf, B.conf, C.conf respectively.

Within the template config file, there is a variable that needs to be set with the A, B, or C respectively as well. I tried to use the `set_fact` and set variable from the list item and reference. I tried to reference `{{ item }}` within. All failed?

```
apps:
 - one
 - two
 - three

tasks:
    - name: Install Logstash config
      template: src={{ upload_dir }}/deploy/logstash-etl.conf dest=/opt/logstash/bin/etl-{{ item }}.conf
      set_fact:
        app: "{{ item }}"
      delegate_to: "{{ logstash_host }}"
      with_items: apps
```

Within the template file I've tried to reference `{{ app }}` and `{{ item }}` and I cannot seem to get it to recognize the dynamic variable to set it's value from the current value of the iteration.

Expected if I had apps: one, two, three would be 3 files in a folder each named etl-one.conf, etl-two.conf, etl-three.conf respectively and within each file a variable in the config dynamically set like "topic_id": "etl.one.Event" for etl-one.conf and "topic_id": "etl.two.Event" for etl-two.conf respectively.

Many thanks for any ideas. The `set_fact` was my latest attempt and that fails with a

```
ERROR: multiple actions specified in task: 'template' and 'Install Logstash config'
exit status 1
```

Comment: I know you got it to work, but just to point out, that error message indicates you are trying to use multiple modules ('template' and 'set_fact') in a single task level. For your case, set_fact is not required, but had it been required, you would have had to write it in as a separate task, not with the 'template' task.

Answer (score 6):

I got it to work without errors. It appears the template CAN reference the `{{ item }}` variable as you iterate so you use it within the template.

```
- name: Install Logstash config
  template: src={{ upload_dir }}/deploy/logstash-etl.conf dest=/opt/logstash/bin/etl-{{ item }}.conf
  delegate_to: "{{ logstash_host }}"
  with_items: apps
```

And in template file:

`"topic_id": "etl.{{ item }}.Event"`